# Why useRef doesn't update when referenced value is updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a code:

```
const page = useRef(1);
const nextPage = useRef(page.current + 1);
```

I was wondering why `nextPage` won't update when I update `page`? Since `nextPage` is referencing `page.current` that is getting updated?

```
page.current = 5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that was working as you expected, there wouldn't be any difference
between

`nextPage = page.current + 1` and `nextPage = useRef(page.current + 1)`.

The argument that is passed into `useRef` is used only once, on first render, after that it keeps the result until you change it. That has nothing to do with the reference, it just accepts the value as it is

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a computed value.

useRef updates isn't supposed to be rendered on the DOM in React...

Instead, you should use useState hook, useMemo to compute and render, like this:

```
function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const nextPage = useMemo(() => page + 1, [page]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{nextPage}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1)}>
        {page}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you know how much more expensive `const nextPage = useMemo(() => page + 1, [page]);` is, compared to `const nextPage = page + 1;`